# illegal operation on a directory open

Tags: node.js

Hey I am trying to upload a file using express-fileupload, but it is failing to move the file to the directory I want I have tried with another project which worked as expected but the current project is not working,

```js
      meetupImage.mv('files/images/',(error) => { /* 
with this existing path it is not working ,  with non existing 
path it is not working also however it works when i use
 "anyname" But not a directory name*/
        if (error) {
          return res.status(500).json({ status: 500, error: `Failled to upload image ${error}`});
        } else {
          const sql = `INSERT INTO meetup_images_table (id, meetup, url) VALUES (1$, $2, 3$) RETURNING *`;
          const newImage = [uuid.v4(),req.params.id, `images/uploaded/${meetupImage.name}`];
          Database.executeQuery(sql, newImage).then((result) => {
            if (result.rows) {
              return res.status(201).json({ status: 201, data: result.rows });
            }
          }).catch(error => res.status(500).json({ status: 500, error: `Server Error ${error}`}));
          return res.status(201).json({ status: 201, data: [meetupImage.name] });
        }
      });
    
      Please hel pem
```

Please Help me I beg U don't Ignore My Question

Answer (score 2):

Oh I am really sorry Guys I was forgetting to add a file name now it is working!!

Forgive me I am really a beginner

Comment: Adding a self-answer is great, but do be sure to include the change you made so the fix is more obvious to someone else in the same situation. Your learning can help others.